# What is the Latin word for 'reading sheet'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

I am looking for a Latin word or phrase that can express the concept of a ‘reading sheet’, which is a document that summarizes the main information of a book or a text. Is there such a word or phrase in classical or medieval Latin? If not, how would you coin one?

Comment: If you (or others) are searching for such a word, you might find it helpful to look for terms like 'summary', 'precis' or 'abstract' rather than 'reading sheet', which doesn't seem to be widely-used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ancient Greeks called this an ἐπιτομή, literally "cutting down". This word was borrowed into Latin as either *epitoma* (-ae) or *epitomē* (-ēs), depending on how pretentious you want to be.

Comment: I thought of using epitome (as in Epitome Historiae Graecae) but was not sure, thanks